# How to install pip for python3.7 only?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have python3.7 and I want to install pip. However when I do the following:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

It seems to download python version 3.6 and pip for **that**. Is there a way to not download python3.6 and just download pip for python3.7? It seems rather strange that pip is download a whole other package.

Comment: There probably isn't a python 3.7 specific version.

Comment: Since 3.4, `pip` is bundled with the standard distribution, so `python3.7 -m pip` will work just fine.

Comment: @hoefling right that's what I use to install new packages. However, having `3.6` installed brings up additional problems (especially with mod_wsgi), so I don't want to install second python3.* version.

Comment: Hm, so just uninstall Python 3.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you check `apt show python3-pip` output you see it depends on `python3:any (>= 3.4~)` so it doesn't strictly say I need python3.6

I assume that you didn't install python3.7 using `apt` so as a result apt doesn't recognize that you have python3 and it tries to install it for you.

Comment: to install python originally, I did: `sudo apt install python3.7`.

Comment: This is wrong at least in Ubuntu 18.04. The `python3-pip` package depends on `python3`. `python3.7` is a separate package, not a version of `python3`. The most up-to-date version of the `python3` package is `3.6.5-3`. Packages that depend on "`python3`" will always install `python3.6`.

Answer (score 16):

Download get-pip file

```
$curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

Install pip for python3.7

```
$python3.7 get-pip.py
```

Check versions for both

```
$python3.7 -V && pip3 -V
Output:
Python 3.7.3
pip 19.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

Comment: Raises `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.cmd'` (Python 3.7.15)

Comment: `sudo apt install python3.7-distutils`

Answer (score 2):

### Deadsnakes

You can use a ppa called deadsnakes.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt install python3.7
```

Then check that is has been installed successfully by running `python3.7 --version`. To use pip you can run `python3.7 -m pip install package`.

### Compiling from source

You can build Python by yourself, on Debian based systems you would do:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev \
libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm \
libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libxml2-dev libxmlsec1-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev
```

Download your preferred python version from https://www.python.org/ftp/python/

Then extract the tar archive and run make

```
./configure --enable-optimizations
make
sudo make altinstall
```

Then run `python3.7 --version`

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
python3.7 -m pip install pip
```

Comment: Adding some commentary will go a long way to explain why this solves the OP's question. Just a code dump alone is not that helpful.